# Loop and Array in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called **SOURCE_TAG** where I want to insert a data where all the insert statements will differ only in one of the columns (this column is a primary key id in a table called **SOURCE_LU** ). However, to get the id of the column I should also do some work.

The following list contains a list of **stringKeys** (a column in **SOURCE_LU**)
So first, I should do some think like the following pseudo code in Oracle SQL

```
stringKeys= {"foo","bar","foobar","barfoo",...,"etc"}
for(each s in StringKeys) {

SELECT SOURCE_LU where stringKeys=s and Store the id in a list (lets say idList)

}
```

after getting the list of id's insert each id in to SOURCE_TAG with other similar data for each row

```
for (each id in listId ){
  INSERT INTO SOURCE_TAG values (x,y,id)

}
```

Sorry, I am a java guy with little SQL knowledge. So how should use Arrays, and loops in Oracle SQL? The simpler the solution the better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL itself doesn’t have loops, but Oracle has a procedural language called PL/SQL that you can use. It has loops, conditionals, variables, and other things you might be used to.

However, I think what you are trying to accomplish can be done in regular SQL. Mind you, I haven’t used an Oracle installation in years and don’t have access to one right now, but in PostgreSQL you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TAG
(YEAR_ID,SOURCE_TAG_LU_ID,PRIORITY_ORDER,STATUS_EN,SOURCE_LU_ID)
select 4 as year_id, 2 as source_tag, 1000 as priority_order, 'ACTIVE' as status_en, id
from source_lu
where stringkeys in ('foo', 'bar', ...)
group by year_id, source_tag, priority_order, status_en, id;
```

It’s possible that `group by id` is enough in the last line.

Comment: i don't have access to create a table.

Comment: I've changed the answer to not require that. As I said I don’t have access to an Oracle installation right now. If you tell me where `x` and `y` come from (are they constants, calculated, or based on other data?), I can give you a more complete example you can easily test.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this one. In the mean time you can give the complete one. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do 
INSERT INTO SOURCE_TAG (YEAR_ID,SOURCE_TAG_LU_ID,PRIORITY_ORDER,STATUS_EN,SOURCE_LU_ID)
 VALUES (4, 2, 1000,'ACTIVE', id) .....
in place of id , I need to user another select statement which will return the list of id's based on the string keys. I am trying to do that right now.

Comment: How do you fill out id? Do you replace id with a select statement? I couldn't understand it.

Comment: The `insert into ... select` form says "run this select query, then insert all the rows into the table". Of course the number of columns returned by your query has to match the number of columns you put in `values(...)`. You could try to run the select part alone to understand.

In the query part, I get all the rows from `source_lu` with a matching `stringkeys`, but then use `group by` to only get the unique IDs. So I am grabbing the IDs from `source_lu`.

I’ve updated the code to match your example. I am assuming that the column in source_lu is called `id`, otherwise you can change that.